# React Native send data to Node.js server with fetch

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, fetch

I'm new to React Native and Node.js so this question may be quite obvious. I have React Native app running from "App.js".

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component 
{
  render() 
  {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.handlePress} title="Press me" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  handlePress() 
  {
    fetch('http://10.222.22.22:3000/',{
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        a: 'hello'
      }),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
    .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

(For security reasons, my IP isn't actually 10.222.22.22).

I also have a Node.js server running from "server.js".

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Here is where I'm trying to access and log the value of "a"
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.a);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

I'm trying to access the value of "a" (from the fetch body in App.js handlePress()) after it is "sent" to the server. So far, nothing shows up on the console aside from "Listening on port 3000". Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You're sure `handlePress` is being called? At a first glance, nothing looks off here.

Comment: @Cristy no errors

Comment: @JackRyan yeah it's being called I had a console log there before

Comment: It looks not connected to server from client. Did you check the client console after fetch?

Answer (score 1):

`ngrok` allows you to expose a web server running on your local machine to the internet.
Ref - [Documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs#:%7E:text=ngrok%20allows%20you%20to%20expose,80%2C%20the%20default%20for%20HTTP.)

The setup is pretty simple.

1. Download ngrok globally from npm by `npm i ngrok -g`
2. Open a terminal and run `ngrok http 3000` (Because your server is running on port 3000)
3. You will get a URL something like `https://3e8a70f45d9b.ngrok.io` (The link will be unique for you)
4. Run your server on another terminal and run your react native app on yet another terminal
5. Now change your URL from http://10.222.22.22:3000/ to the link you got from step 3.

> Note: Logging in on ngrok.com allows you to have additional time for your sessions unlike the default timeout session which is 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your `handlePress` as an arrow function.

```
 handlePress = () => {
    // ... your fetch code
 }
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, as it doesn't access any class members, it could as well be a static function.